# How to extend this integration to all the reals?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, trigonometry

Doing an exercise on calculus with 12.2 on Windows 10 Pro, I obtain

```
a = Integrate[Sqrt[1 + Sin[t]], {t, 0, x}, Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[ 4*Sqrt[2]*IntegerPart[x/(2*Pi)] +  Piecewise[ {{(-2*Cos[x/2]*(-1 +  Sqrt[1 + Sin[x]]) +    2*Sin[x/2]*(1 + Sqrt[1 + Sin[x]]))/(Cos[x/2] +  Sin[x/2]), Inequality[-1/4, Less, FractionalPart[ x/(2*Pi)], Less, 3/4]}},  (2*Sin[x/2]*(1 - 2*Sqrt[2] +  Sqrt[1 + Sin[x]]) -  2*Cos[x/2]*(-1 + 2*Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[1 + Sin[x]]))/(Cos[x/2] + Sin[x/2])],  x < (3*Pi)/2]`

I am surprised by the condition `x < (3*Pi)/2`, but this is necessary in that output as

```
Plot[ 4*Sqrt[2]*IntegerPart[x/(2*Pi)] + 
Piecewise[ {{(-2*Cos[x/2]*(-1 +  Sqrt[1 + Sin[x]]) +    2*Sin[x/2]*(1 +
Sqrt[1 + Sin[x]]))/(Cos[x/2] +  Sin[x/2]), Inequality[-1/4, Less, FractionalPart[x/(2*Pi)], 
Less, 3/4]}},  (2*Sin[x/2]*(1 - 2*Sqrt[2] +  Sqrt[1 + Sin[x]]) - 
2*Cos[x/2]*(-1 + 2*Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[1 + Sin[x]]))/(Cos[x/2] + Sin[x/2])],{x, -4*Pi, 4*Pi}]
```

[image]

shows (The definite integral of a continuous function is a continuous function of its upper limit of integration.).
I understand there are branch points of the integrand at $t=- \frac \pi 2 +2\pi n,\, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ in the complex plane
, but I don't understand the difference of the behavior of `a` near $x=-\frac \pi 2$ and $ x=\frac {3\pi} 2$.

The question is: how to obtain a formula for `Integrate[Sqrt[1 + Sin[t]], {t, 0, x},  Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]` which is valid for all the real values of `x`?

Comment: Things are a little easier if you express `Sqrt[1 + Sin[t]]` as `Sqrt[2] Sin[π/4 + t/2]`.

Comment: @J.M.,This results in `4 Sin[x/4]^2 + 2 Sin[x/2]` which is not correct. Indeed, `Integrate[Sqrt[2] RealAbs[Sin[π/4 + t/2]], {t, 0, x}, Assumptions -> x ∈ Reals]` does the job though the crucial step is made by hand. Please, submit your comment as an answer.

Comment: In that case, I hope someone else can derive the result `2 Sqrt[2] (t/π - 1/2 - Csc[π/4 + t/2] Sin[π/4 - t/2] Sqrt[Sin[π/4 + t/2]^2] + 2/π ArcTan[Tan[π/4 - t/2]])` for you in the meantime.

Comment: J.M., BTW, `Assuming[t ∈ Reals, Sqrt[1 + Sin[t]] == Sqrt[2] RealAbs[Sin[π/4 + t/2]]]` returns the input.

Comment: @J.M. Sorry, but `Plot[2 Sqrt[
   2] (t/\[Pi] - 1/2 - 
    Csc[\[Pi]/4 + t/2] Sin[\[Pi]/4 - t/2] Sqrt[
      Sin[\[Pi]/4 + t/2]^2] + 
    2/\[Pi] ArcTan[Tan[\[Pi]/4 - t/2]]), {t, -8, 8}]` omits the origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing `1+Sin[t] >= 0`  Mathematica evaluates

```
intx=Integrate[Sqrt[RealAbs[1 + Sin[t]]], {t, 0 , x}]
```

for `x \[Element] Real`

[image]

```
Plot[intx,{x,-2 Pi,2 Pi}]
```

[image]

**addendum**

Mathematica gives a slightly simpler solution if the integration range is shifted about `-Pi/2` . That's permissible because the integrand is periodic:

```
Integrate[Sqrt[Abs[ 1 + Sin[t]]] , {t, -Pi/2, x - Pi/2}] // Simplify
```

[image]

Comment: Let us consider `a = Integrate[Sqrt[1 + 2*Sin[t]], {t, 0, x}, 
  Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]`. In this case Mathematica results in `ConditionalExpression[
 2*Sqrt[3]*(EllipticE[Pi/4, 4/3] - 
   EllipticE[(Pi - 2*x)/4, 4/3]), 
 x < (7*Pi)/6 && Sin[x] >= -1/2]` and your approach does not work. Thank you anyway.

Comment: You should consider the same integral as I did. Radicant `1 + 2*Sin[t]` is wrong!

Comment: UlrichNeumann (@does not work.). The integral `Integrate[Sqrt[1 + 2*Sin[t]], {t, 0, x},    Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]` exists and is a (complex-valued) continuous function. Hope, I am clear. A good approach should have a reserve.

Comment: @user64494  My answer starts with an assumption, which your example doesn't fullfill. My answer considers what  you asked for in your question, not  more!

Comment: UlrichNeumann (@does not work.) I'l wait some time for other answers before accepting your tricky (not clever) answer. BTW, `1+Sin[t]>=0`, not `1+Sin[t]>0` for real values of `t`.

Comment: Your distinction  tricky vs clever is dispensable: Currently my answer is the only which solves your question using Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

A continuous function is

```
2 + 4*Sqrt[2]*Floor[(Pi + 2*x)/(4*Pi)] - (2*Cos[x])/Sqrt[1 + Sin[x]]
```

found by manually adjusting the location of the jumps in the argument of the floor function and the height of the jumps by looking at left and right limits.

Comment: This can also be expressed as `2 - Sqrt[2] + 2 Sqrt[2]/π (x - 2 ArcTan[Tan[x/2 - π/4]]) - 2 Cos[x]/Sqrt[1 + Sin[x]]`.

Comment: First, I am interested in the integration produced by Mathematica. Second, `FullSimplify[
 D[2 + 4*Sqrt[2]*Floor[(Pi + 2*x)/(4*Pi)] - (2*Cos[x])/
    Sqrt[1 + Sin[x]], x], Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]` performs $$\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \sqrt{\sin (x)+1} & 2 x+\pi >4 \pi  \left\lfloor \frac{2 x+\pi }{4 \pi }\right\rfloor  \\
 \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array} .$$Thank you anyway.

Comment: @user64494 try to plot the function...

Comment: @j.m.'ennui interesting way of expressing the floor function